# How to set HTML attribute with @yield of Laravel?

Tags: php, templates, laravel, yield

I'm trying create a template for my control panel

I want make a "Back" button in the template, where I can set your `href` is set for extended page 
So I tried use @yield for set, but not have success

Fallowing my code

```
// in my template  ->  layouts.master.blade.php
<a href="@yield('back')">Back</a>



//my extended page ->  user.edit.blade.php
@extends('../layouts.master')

@section('back')
    dashboard
@stop
```

Comment: back and voltar? Is this just a typo?

Comment: if is not possible set attribute with @yield, have any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not working for you, but it should. Here's a test I just did on my end. I got a clean Laravel app, renamed home.php to

#### layout.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>
    <style>
        @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);

        body {
            margin:0;
            font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
            text-align:center;
            color: #999;
        }

        .welcome {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: -150px;
            margin-top: -100px;
        }

        a, a:visited {
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 32px;
            margin: 16px 0 0 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="welcome">
        <a href="@yield('laraveldotcom')" title="Laravel PHP Framework"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Laravel PHP Framework"></a>
        <h1>@yield('youhave')</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I'm using two different yields, wich you'll see in the new

#### home.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')

@section('youhave')
  You have arrived.
@stop

@section('laraveldotcom')
  http://laravel.com
@stop
```

And it worked fine for me, I could even click the Laravel logo to be redirected to the Laravel site. So you might have a problem somewhere else.